# Is there a way to write a polymorphic template function?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Let's say I have a function

```
template <typename T>
T foo() {
    // do stuff  
    return T(/* some value*/);
}
```

so I could call it for example like this:

```
int my_int = foo<int>();
std::string my_string = foo<std::string>();
```

Is there any way for me to create 2 separate polymorphic functions such that I could have a function that only gets called if `T` is `std::string`?

I tried doing this using the following code:

```
template <typename T>
T foo() {
    if (std::is_same<std::string, T>::value) {
       // do string specific stuff

    }

    return T(/* some value */);
}
```

but I would get compilation errors as the operations I wanted to do when `T` was `std::string` did not work when `T` was other types. Is there any way to make this polymorphic or should I just use a different function name like `fooString()`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: If you want a specific behavior when `T` is `std::string`, why not simply have an overload?

Comment: @piwi You mean specialize?

Comment: @LogicStuff no, overload.

Comment: Lookup the CRTP and _static polymorphism_.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz But there are no parameters to overload on.

Comment: @LogicStuff My bad.

Comment: Since function template specialization is [discouraged](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm), you could also introduce a tag to utilize the overload mechanism for a parameterless function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SFINAE

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<false == std::is_same<T, std::string>::value, T>::type
      foo ()
 {
   std::cout << "- generic foo()" << std::endl;

   return T{};
 }

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<true == std::is_same<T, std::string>::value, T>::type
      foo ()
 {
   std::cout << "- std::string foo()" << std::endl;

   return T{""};
 }

int main()
 {
   foo<int>();                       // print - generic foo()
   foo<std::complex<long double>>(); // print - generic foo()
   foo<std::string>();               // print - std::string foo()
 }
```

Comment: and this is what `if constexpr` will fix in C++17

Comment: @BoundaryImposition - Yes; I can't wait for a gcc or clang with a full C++17 support.

Answer (score 3):

You can use template specialisation:

```
template <typename T>
T foo() { //v1
    return T(/* some value */);
}

template <>
std::string foo() { // v2
    return "Hello World !";
}
```

When called with a string (as template parameter), the version 2 of `foo` will be called. Otherwise it's the version 1.

**EDIT**

Check out  @BartekBanachewicz comment to the question for information about why you should not use function template specialisation.